# how to copy a column from one datagrid into another

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Given two WPF data grids, would it be possible to copy the data from one Datagrid column into the other programmatically?

So all of the data in `DataGrid A`, `columns[1]` would be passed into `Datagrid B`, `columns[2]`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?  It might be a better option, depending on your use case, to just bind a single underlying items collection to both grids and then have one of the properties show in both.

Comment: Import a csv. which is variable in it's arrangement and datatypes, and then direct it into a new table/grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So copying from DataGrid A (dialog.displayTable), to DataGrid B (just displayTable) I did it by iterating through DataGrid A row by row, and then copying the column data into a new row, column by column. Then adding that row to the DataGrid B.

In this example I also used a separate DataGrid with headers set to ComboBox's to re-map the columns if I so chose.

```
   foreach(DataRow displayRow in ((DataView)dialog.displayTable.ItemsSource).ToTable().Rows)
    {
        int i = 0;
        DataRow drNew = displayTable.NewRow();
        foreach (DataGridColumn selectedCol in dialog.SelectionTable.Columns)
        {

            drNew[(selectedCol.Header as ComboBox).SelectedIndex] = displayRow[i];
            i++;
        }
        displayTable.Rows.Add(drNew.ItemArray);
    }
```